# в чем ошибка он выводит не правильно

Tags: python

```
import random 
knb = int(input('Камень(1), ножницы(2), бумага(3),? ')) 
comp = random.randint(1, 3) 
print(comp) 
if knb == 1 or comp == 2: 
    print("вы вииграли он достал ножницы") 
elif knb == 1 or comp == 3: 
    print("вы проиграли он достал бумагу") 
elif knb == 1 or comp == 1: 
    print("НИЧЬЯ он достал камень") 
elif knb == 2 or comp == 1: 
    print("вы проиграли он достал камень") 
elif knb == 2 or comp == 2: 
    print("НИЧЬЯ он достал ножнецы") 
elif knb == 2 or comp == 3: 
    print("вы выиграли он достал бумагу") 
elif knb == 3 or comp == 1: 
    print("вы выграли он достал камень") 
elif knb == 3 or comp == 2: 
    print("вы проиграли он достал ножнецы") 
elif knb == 3 or comp == 3: 
    print("НИЧЬЯ он достал бумагу") 
else: 
    print("чё вы написали?")
```

в переменую comp водит одно число а потом меняет число это понятно по такому примеру:
Камень(1), ножницы(2), бумага(3),? 1
3
вы вииграли он достал ножницы

Comment: `or` на `and` поменяйте

Answer (score 2):

Перед решением задачи лучше составить какой-нить алгоритм, чтобы свести проверки к минимуму, например, если не сравнивать числа между собой, а проверять их разницу, получается очень компактная функция:

```
def a():
    s = int(input('Камень(1), ножницы(2), бумага(3),? '))
    ss = random.randint(1, 3)
    print(ss)
    if s == ss:
        return 'Ничья'
    elif s - ss in (-1, 2):
        return 'Вы выиграли'
    else:
        return 'Вы проиграли'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 
knb = int(input('Камень(1), ножницы(2), бумага(3),? ')) 
comp = random.randint(1, 3) 
print(comp) 
if knb == 1 and comp == 2: 
    print("Вы выиграли, он достал ножницы") 
elif knb == 1 and comp == 3: 
    print("Вы проиграли, он достал бумагу") 
elif knb == 1 and comp == 1: 
    print("НИЧЬЯ! Он достал камень") 
elif knb == 2 and comp == 1: 
    print("Вы проиграли, он достал камень") 
elif knb == 2 and comp == 2: 
    print("НИЧЬЯ! Он достал ножницы") 
elif knb == 2 and comp == 3: 
    print("Вы выиграли, он достал бумагу") 
elif knb == 3 and comp == 1: 
    print("Вы выиграли, он достал камень") 
elif knb == 3 and comp == 2: 
    print("Вы проиграли, он достал ножницы") 
elif knb == 3 and comp == 3: 
    print("НИЧЬЯ! Он достал бумагу") 
else: 
    print("Простите, этого я не предусмотрел")
```

Answer (score 0):

Замените **or** на **and**. По логике написанной программы оно доходит до первого условия if, сравнивает переменную knp с 1 (knp==1) и получается true.

С логическим оператором **or** общее условие будет true, если хоть одно из субусловий равно true (как тут), т.е. `if 1==1 or 2==3` то же самое, что и `if true or false` и получаем в условии true.

С логическим оператором **and** общее условие будет true, если оба субусловия равны true, т.е. `if 1==1 and 2==3` то же самое, что и `if true and false` и получаем в условии false.